# Python: Dynamically named imported class not recognised under globals

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a problem with running some code in python, it goes as follows.
My first module looks as follows:

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self, var, name=None):
        self.var = var
        self.__class__.name = name

def func():
    print(globals()[obj.name].var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = obj('var','inst')
    func()
```

When I run this it simply outputs:

```
var
```

...as would be expected.
The second piece of code then imports the first module and tries to run the same code as seen in the bottom of the module:

```
from key_example import *

inst = obj('var','inst')
func()
```

But when I run this it throws the error of:

```
print(globals()[obj.name].var)
KeyError: 'inst'
```

Now it is probably due to a misunderstanding in the functioning of globals(), but does anyone know why this, or could explain to me what I would need to change for my second module to output var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Python documentation [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

So let's explain it within an example.

Let's have a first file called **file_globals.py**:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, var, name=None):
        self.var = var
        self.__class__.name = name

def func():
    print(globals().keys())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst_file1 = Obj('var1', 'inst1')
    func()
```

if you run:

```
$ python3 file_globals.py
```

Will return:

```
dict_keys(['__cached__', '__doc__', '__spec__', '__loader__', 'func', '__package__', 'Obj', '__file__', 'inst_file1', '__name__', '__builtins__'])
```

Then let's create another file called **file2_globals.py** :

```
from file_globals import *

inst_file2 = Obj('var2', 'inst2')
print(globals().keys())
```

Then run:

```
$ python3 file2_globals.py
```

Will return:

```
dict_keys(['__loader__', '__file__', 'inst_file2', '__name__', 'func', 'Obj', '__spec__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__builtins__'])
```

So, as you see, globals() will only return the current global symbol table of where you called the globals() method.

So, a quick fix to your code, you can do something like this:

**file_globals.py**

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, var, name=None):
        self.var = var
        self.__class__.name = name

def func(cls):
    if isinstance(cls, Obj):
        print(cls.name, cls.var)
    else:
        print('None!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst_file1 = Obj('var1', 'inst1')
    func(inst_file1)
```

If you run it you'll have:

```
$ python3 file_globals.py
inst1 var1
```

**file2_globals.py**

```
from file_globals import *

inst_file2 = Obj('var2', 'inst2')
func(inst_file2)
```

if you run it you'll have:

```
$ python3 file2_globals.py
inst2 var2
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your help with this code and the swift response, it is incredibly appreciated! Tested it out in my other code and it works perfectly (not to mention much neater) :)

Comment: Thanks. You can validate my answer if it reponds to your question. Happy coding.

Comment: I have done :)  I unfortunately don't have sufficient reputation to upvote this but thank you again!

Comment: Welcome. Also, a good place to improve your programming skills within Python is by reading the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). Happy coding.